# How to get an image input using argparse and pass it into a function?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, argparse

I'm trying to build a cli tool for converting images to black-and-white.
How do I pass my filepath into the function and return the no color image ?
This is my boilerplate code so far.

```
import argparse
import PIL 
def main():
    def black_white(src):
        img = Image.open('%s'%(src))
        img = img.convert('1')
        img.save('result.png')
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= 'Image Decolouriser')
    parser.add_argument('-black_white','-bg', help= 'converts to no color !!')

    if args.black_white:
        black_white(args.black_white())


if __name__ == __main__:
    main()
```

Comment: Please go through argparse docs once it should help : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: The Documentation is kinda not concise for passing function calls in argparse. If you find them please reply the link here.

Comment: Please check answer given by `rotosizero`. It should be working. Start the program as `python program.py path_to_image_file`

Comment: `args.black_white` is a string, not a function.  During debugging it's a good idea to add a `print(args)` so you see exactly what the parser has produced.  That way you won't be guessing about attribute names or values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
def main():
    def black_white(src):
        img = Image.open('%s'%(src))
        img = img.convert('1')
        img.save('result.png')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= 'Image Decolouriser')
    parser.add_argument('black_white', help= 'image to convert')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    black_white(args.black_white)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example call

```
my_prog image_path
```

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle